# DynamoDB query returns empty object when called from http server in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am node.js learner.I have written a local file which will connect to dynamo db service from my local m/c and do a query.I have exported the function which does the query.
Now I have created a http local server in node.js and called the exported function which will call the dynamo db query.
I have used promise in while doing the query to dynamo db but getting empty object.
when I am executing the dynamodb query function standalone means just calling the function from same file
it is returning values as expected but when calling the function from http server then I am facing the issue of empty object.

```
var AWS = require("aws-sdk");
var awsConfig = {
    "region": "us-east-1",
    "endpoint": "http://dynamodb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
};

if (typeof Promise === 'undefined') {
    AWS.config.setPromisesDependency(require('bluebird'));
  }

const loadCarDetailsWithImage = async function (pKeyValueModelNo,sKeyValueCarName) {

    AWS.config.update(awsConfig);

    var docClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

    console.log(pKeyValueModelNo);
    console.log(sKeyValueCarName);

    var params = {
        TableName: "ImageDetails",

        ProjectionExpression:"ModelNo,CarName,ImageUrl",
        KeyConditionExpression: "ModelNo = :mdNo and CarName = :carName",
        ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ":mdNo": pKeyValueModelNo,
            ":carName": sKeyValueCarName
        },



    };


    //1.Tried like this as option 1
    //but data is empty
    await docClient.query(params).promise().then(function(data) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
      }).catch(function(err) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
      });




    //2.Tried alternative way as option 2
    //but data is empty
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        docClient.query(params, function (err, data) {
            if (err) {
                console.log("error - " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
                reject(err);
            }
            else {
                console.log("success - " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
                resolve(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2));
            }
        })

    })

}

module.exports = loadCarDetailsWithImage;
```

The called function which is called when a req is received in http server is like

```
var car = require('./loadCarDetailsWithImage'); // this I have written at beginning

function callBusinessProcess(id,carName,res){
        console.log("id: "+id+" and name: "+carName);
        var initializePromise =   car(id,carName);
        initializePromise.then(function(result) {
            console.log(result);
            res = result;
        },function(err){
            console.log(err);
        }).then(function(result){
            console.log(result);
        })

    }
```

OutPut is coming like:

```
success - {
  "Items": [],
  "Count": 0,
  "ScannedCount": 0
}
{
  "Items": [],
  "Count": 0,
  "ScannedCount": 0
}
```

called the function like

```
if(req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get'
           && req.url.substring(0,9) == '/content/'){

            var q = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
            console.log("Model No :"+q.model);
            console.log("Car Name :"+q.name);
           callBusinessProcess(q.model,q.name,res);


           }
```

also having the variables values in output like below.These values are available in db

```
Model No :bmwx1
Car Name :BMW
pKeyValueModelNo :bmwx1
sKeyValueCarName :BMW
```

I am very confused that though I have used promise in my function still I am receiving empty object

Comment: can you also show how are you calling `callBusinessProcess(id,carName,res){` and also make sure you are getting value of id and carName

Comment: if(req.method.toLowerCase() == 'get'
           && req.url.substring(0,9) == '/content/'){
        
            var q = url.parse(req.url,true).query;
            console.log("Model No :"+q.model);
            console.log("Car Name :"+q.name);
           callBusinessProcess(q.model,q.name,res);
       

           }  .

and I am getting values in my req..output I got for printing attributes from url
Model No :bmwx1
Car Name :BMW
pKeyValueModelNo :bmwx1
sKeyValueCarName :BMW
users::fetchOneByKey::success - {
  "Items": [],
  "Count": 0,
  "ScannedCount": 0
}

Comment: can you add this info in your question as it is very hard to read it from here

Comment: Modified the info in my actual qs

Comment: when you directly call loadCarDetailsWithImage with pKeyValueModelNo :bmwx1
sKeyValueCarName :BMW, does it give response?

Comment: Thanks for your response.I just found the issue.No issue in code.There is a space added mistakenly in the DB value.So for this data set the query did not work as no space was provided in the input param.After checking so many things at last I found the issue.We can close this issue now.